# Changing rotation of a UIBezierPath in SpriteKit without changing orientation

Tags: xcode, swift, sprite-kit

I'm making a game. I want 2 separate lines to rotate clockwise and when the player touches the screen the rotation should change to counterclockwise. Right now, when it changes to counterclockwise, the `UIBezierPath` flips the node. I don't want the node to be flipped, just rotate the other way.

```
func clockwise() {
    let dx = leftside.position.x - self.frame.width / 2
    let dy = leftside.position.y - self.frame.height / 2

    let rad = atan2(dy, dx)
    let path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2, y: self.frame.height / 2), radius: 85, startAngle: rad, endAngle: rad + CGFloat(M_PI * 4), clockwise: true)

    let follow = SKAction.followPath(path.CGPath, asOffset: false, orientToPath: true, speed: 250)

    leftside.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(follow).reversedAction())

    let dx1 = rightside.position.x - self.frame.width / 2
    let dy1 = rightside.position.y - self.frame.height / 2

    let rad1 = atan2(dy1, dx1)
    let path1 = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2, y: self.frame.height / 2), radius: 85, startAngle: rad1, endAngle: rad1 + CGFloat(M_PI * 4), clockwise: true)

    let follow1 = SKAction.followPath(path1.CGPath, asOffset: false, orientToPath: true, speed: 250)

    rightside.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(follow1).reversedAction())       
}


func counterclockwise() {
    let dx = leftside.position.x - self.frame.width / 2
    let dy = leftside.position.y - self.frame.height / 2

    let rad = atan2(dy, dx)
    let path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2, y: self.frame.height / 2), radius: 85, startAngle: rad, endAngle: rad + CGFloat(M_PI * 4), clockwise: true)

    let follow = SKAction.followPath(path.CGPath, asOffset: false, orientToPath: true, speed: 250)

    leftside.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(follow))          
    let dx1 = rightside.position.x - self.frame.width / 2
    let dy1 = rightside.position.y - self.frame.height / 2

    let rad1 = atan2(dy1, dx1)
    let path1 = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2, y: self.frame.height / 2), radius: 85, startAngle: rad1, endAngle: rad1 + CGFloat(M_PI * 4), clockwise: true)

    let follow1 = SKAction.followPath(path1.CGPath, asOffset: false, orientToPath: true, speed: 250)

    rightside.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(follow1))
}
```

Comment: Instead of calling `reversedAction()` at the end, how about just setting `clockwise` to `false` when creating the `UIBezierPath`?

Comment: i tried that, when i set clockwise to false, the rotating doesnt happen. doesn't rotation at any direction